# cant Insert data into SQLite-android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to add data into my created SQLite database with SQLite database manager programs i get the "readonly database"error

When i comment insertion line the program works fine and crashes when uncommented.

Note : I have requested read/write storage permission and it has been granted.

```
public static Context context;
public static SQLiteDatabase database;
public static String SDK = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
public static String DB = SDK + "/database/";

context = getApplicationContext();

File file = new File(DB);
file.mkdirs();
database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB + "/db.sqlite",null);
database  = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB + "/db.sqlite",null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
database.execSQL("CREATE  TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS 'tbltest' ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , 'name' VARCHAR, 'family' VARCHAR)");
database.execSQL("INSERT INTO `tbltest` (`name`,`family`) VALUES (`John`,`Doe`)");
database.close();
```

**Logcat error**

```
     `    --------- beginning of crash
04-19 20:54:50.832 13353-13353/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: andishmand.database, PID: 13353
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{andishmand.database/andishmand.database.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: John (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO `tbltest` (`name`,`family`) VALUES (`John`,`Doe`)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: John (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO `tbltest` (`name`,`family`) VALUES (`John`,`Doe`)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
                                                       at andishmand.database.MainActivity.executecommand(MainActivity.java:128)
                                                       at andishmand.database.MainActivity.createdb(MainActivity.java:115)
                                                       at andishmand.database.MainActivity.requestperms(MainActivity.java:100)
                                                       at andishmand.database.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
04-19 20:54:50.853 1610-3265/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity andishmand.database/.MainActivity`
```

Comment: Please use the SQLiteOpenHelper which is explained here : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html
(or realm)

Comment: Also,  those warnings lines are not from your app.  can you change it to the actual error logs from the crash?

Comment: @petey thanks for answer , i added actual error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Confirm that the device database is the way you want it as in your create statement in case your table was previously created without a column. You can do this by uninstalling the app and redeploying it.
2. Then use `ContentValues` class and the `database.insert` to do the actual insert. A good deal of this is explained here : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html, but here is the short and simple:

remove this line :

```
database.execSQL("INSERT INTO `tbltest` (`name`,`family`) VALUES (`John`,`Doe`)");
```

And replace it with :

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("name", "John");
values.put("family", "Doe");
long insertedRowId = database.insert("tbltest", null, values);
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL uses "double quotes" to quote table/column names, and 'single quotes' to quote strings.

`Backticks` are a misguided attempt to be MySQL compatible; don't use them, ever.